# Kendo function MVVM bind

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-template

I'm tried to use kendo function mvvm binding with constant like shown here:
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/mvvm-pass-parameters-from-view-to-view-model-function

```
<div data-bind="visible: visibleTextBox('2q4')"></div>
```

But if I add >2 arguments, or add dots into constant

```
<div data-bind="visible: visibleTextBox('2q4', '2q4', '2q4')"></div>
<div data-bind="visible: visibleTextBox('2.q.4')"></div>
```

It's return error:

> result:4 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Can someone tell, why does this happen, and how to fix this?

Here is dojo:
https://dojo.telerik.com/iJAXajEg

Comment: You can pass only one String parameter, in that parameter you can add as many data as you want separated with delimiter (in this case q). You can send '2q3q4q5123123' and get an array of parameters: ['2','3','4','5123123']. I can see it doesn't work with . or , delimiter. Probably because of some regex expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is straight up in the link at the beginning of your question:

> if you need to pass an array, pass it as a string with a certain delimiter.

If you need a 2-dimentional array, use 2 delimiters:

```
"1q3p2q4".split("p").map(x => x.split("q"))
```

will give you:

```
[[1, 3],[2, 4]]
```